# Generalizations of Deuring's correspondence

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, quaternions

Deuring's correspondence gives a bijection between maximal orders of quaternion algebras and supersingular elliptic curves (put simply). For maximal orders in central simple algebras of degree larger than two, are there similar bijections to different classes of curve? that is, are there other 'Deuring-like' correspondences for maximal orders in CSAs that are not quaternionic?

Comment: There is a whole theory of [complex multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication_of_abelian_varieties) for abelian varieties. One reference is Milne's course notes: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cm.html